# How to await function completion with a loop inside

Tags: autohotkey

In the script included below I try to run a chain of commands. But when run by pressing F1 the command will run both `SendAndLoopFor()` invocations immediately after each other without waiting for the inner loop to complete.

I tried to 'force' this await by adding a return "" inside the function, and assigning a variable with it instead `Foo := SendAndLoopFor()` but even then it would not await the operation.

Is there a way to await the completion of the `SendAndLoopFor()` command before executing the next?

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 13
#SingleInstance
F1::
Done = 0
Toggle := !Toggle
Loop
{
    If (!Toggle)
        Break
    SendAndLoopFor("4", -13600)
    SendAndLoopFor("5", -13600)
}
return

SendAndLoopFor(TSend="", Timeout=0)
{
    Send %TSend%
    SetTimer, LoopLimit, %Timeout%
    Loop
    {
        If(!Toggle)
            Break
        If(done == 1)
        {
            done = 0
            Break
        }
        MouseClick, left
        sleep 83
    }
}
LoopLimit:
    Done = 1
Return
```

Comment: You need a return before SendAndLoopFor(). And you refer to a non-existent label named LoopLimit

Comment: Ah i indeed forgot to include that piece. Ill edit it in later

Comment: AutoHotkey does run them in sequence, but your `SendAndLoopFor` loop has a `Sleep` time of only 83 milliseconds. Is this intentional? Because your current delay will be almost imperceptible.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe but the loop will go on, till interupted or for the timeout duration.which in the sample is 13.6 seconds. Thats what the settimer part is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to stem from a misunderstanding of SetTimer. It's an excellent tool for parallelizing tasks, because the script inherently **does not** wait for the timer before proceeding down the script.

To illustrate this, simplify the script and you can observe the same effect.

```
F3::
SetTimer, LoopLimit, -2000
SendInput, This is stuff happening before the timer.{Enter}
return

LoopLimit:
SendInput, This is stuff happening after.
```

A simple solution is counting iterations and killing the loop after hitting the counter limit.

```
F3::
count = 0

Loop
{
; Do stuff.

count += 1
Sleep, 1000

if (count >= 5)
{
break
}}
```

You can also use [various built-in variables](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm) to compare times from the start of the loop to your cut off value, but these can be a pain to work with, so I recommend avoiding them unless your script is working within time-sensitive constraints.

**Edit per the comments:**

```
F1::
Done = 0
Toggle := !Toggle
Loop
{
    If (!Toggle)
        Break
    SendAndLoopFor("4", -13600)
    SendAndLoopFor("5", -13600)
    Sleep, 2000
}
return

SendAndLoopFor(TSend="", Timeout=0)
{
    Send %TSend%
    SetTimer, LoopLimit, %Timeout%
    Loop
    {
        If(!Toggle)
        {
            SendInput, This is inside the Toggle.{Enter}
            Break
        }
        If(done == 1)
        {
            SendInput, This is inside the Done.{Enter}
            done = 0
            Break
        }
        SendInput, This is after the If statements.{Enter}
        MouseClick, left
        Sleep, 999999 ; Note how this has no effect due to above break.
    }
}
LoopLimit:
    Done = 1
```

Comment: It's not the loop part that I am having a issue with though. It is the chain of function invocations.     `SendAndLoopFor("4", -13600)` which, internally loops it's 'click' command as it should. But at the same time the other     `SendAndLoopFor("5", -13600)` is also invoked. Without awaiting the first invocations completion.

Comment: @MXD I don't suppose you've had a chance to test each of the conditional statements in your loop? Your `If(!Toggle)` inside `SendAndLoopFor` is always true, and thus the loop always breaks. Because you have no Sleep commands with a delay large enough to be perceptible, they appear to fire at the same time, but this isn't the case. They just complete that fast. I'll edit my answer with a modification of your code to showcase this.

Comment: effectively I use the If(!Toggle) in another, script in an identical way. Where it works, just fine. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/36e75336eec880016bc6aef81861edcf  (the full script) The sample of my code above makes use of this exact same code, but extracts the copy pasted code into function, making the code drier. Also if the ' Toggle statement would always be true, it wouldn't run to begin with. Considering it is also in the first loop, the one invoking the commands.

Comment: @MXD Try the script and see for yourself. You don't get farther than the first If statement.

Comment: I did, my problem didn't stem from the settimer. But the fact that the variable `Toggle` was scoped, thus did not exist in the called function. By defining the variable in the `SendAndLoopFor()` as well I got it to work.

Comment: @MXD I'm glad you figured it out. :)